# Node.js: Getting Invalid RSAES-OAEP padding when trying to decrypt an encrypted symmetric key

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, rsa, cryptojs

I have a usecase where I want to encrypt my data first with a symmetric key and then encrypt the symmetric key with the client's public key. I tried to mock the scenario, but getting 'Invalid RSAES-OAEP padding' error.

Code:

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var _crypto = require('crypto');
var rsa = forge.pki.rsa;

var masterKey = _crypto.randomBytes(32);
var keypair = rsa.generateKeyPair(2048);
var encryptedVal = keypair.publicKey.encrypt(masterKey, 'RSA-OAEP');
var decryptedVal = keypair.privateKey.decrypt(encryptedVal, 'RSA-OAEP');
console.log(masterKey,decryptedVal)
```

Do I have to convert the symmetric key format before encrypting it? And if yes, to what?

Answer (score 2):

`masterKey` is a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). You need to convert it to bytes so forge can use it

Try this function (I didn't test it...)

```
function toBytes(buf) {
    var byteString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
        byteString += String.fromCodePoint(buf[i]);
    }
    return byteString;
}
```

Usage

```
var masterKey = toBytes(_crypto.randomBytes(32));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't use this function but converting buffer to string helped. I used masterKey.toString('base64') before encrypting and after decryption, got the masterKey back using new Buffer(key, 'base64').

Comment: It is also a valid solution because base64 is a way to encode binary data with a 64 character alphabet, and the result is a char array. Consider to mark the answer as accepted or upvote when you have enough reputation